# How to make my program run continously

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to make my program run continously so that when it is done it will run again after 2 seconds.

Heres my code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var colorBlocks = [
    'skip',
    'yellow',
    'green',
    'blue',
    'white',
    'orange'
]

function colourBoard() {
    $.each(colorBlocks, function (i) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#' + this).css("background", this);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#' + this).css("background", '#212121');
            }.bind(this), i * 200);
        }.bind(this), i * 500);
    });
}
colourBoard();
});
```

Comment: Use `setInterval()` to run something repeatedly.

Answer (score 2):

I would sugget using [`setInterval()`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) for this:

```
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
}
```

Comment: You can also use the 'clearInterval()' method if you want or need to stop the interval, either through a button click event or you could have it happen after a set number of iterations.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the function call itself when it gets to last change.

```
function colourBoard() {
    $.each(colorBlocks, function (i) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#' + this).css("background", this);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#' + this).css("background", '#212121');

                // start over if it's the last one
                if(i === colorBlocks.length-1){
                   colourBoard();
                }


            }.bind(this), i * 200);
        }.bind(this), i * 500);
    });
}
colourBoard();
```

Pros: Using setInterval doesn't start getting ahead of the timers in function

Cons: Requires a bit more logic to pause/restart than using setInterval